# Why doesn't Stack Exchange support 2-factor authentication (2FA)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, login

Why doesn't Stack Exchange support 2-factor authentication (2FA)? If I put this in as a feature-request, will the powers that be consider it?

Comment: The purpose of two-factor authentication is to verify that you are who you say you are to the system.  Wouldn't you have to force everyone to use it for it to have any value?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No. It's useful on an account-by-account basis. If any given person is worried about someone else guessing/obtaining their password, they could enable 2FA for their account to reduce that risk. For example, staff/moderators might be worried about someone breaking into their accounts and going on a privilege-misuse spree. 2FA on their accounts would prevent that, without requiring every normal user to have it.

Comment: It's 2019, can this be revisited? The accepted answer isn't a true solution for the reasons mentioned in the comments.

Comment: A hacked email and a password reset - then your account is lost even when you have 2FA on the other logins.

We have U2F nowadays - at least we should have TOTP 2FA on stackexchange.
Please take it up again - thanks

Comment: It is very embarrassing that SO doesn't support 2FA. I would even expect it to fully support MFA!

Comment: In a world increasingly full of breaches and cyber security concerns, I'm at a loss for why Stack Overflow, a *programming-focused* Q&A site, doesn't concern itself enough with said security to implement a 2FA solution that doesn't rely on some 3rd party account linking. It outright looks bad in 2021 IMO, and is less and less excusable as the feature increasingly becomes standard fare on every other major platform out there. It's time for this to be formally revisited.

Comment: I agree with the comments above. It is very strange that a programming-focussed website does not provides a 2-factor authentication log-in method. I am confident that many programming-minded people on StackOverflow will start using 2FA when available (or promoted).

Moreover, as this post has been closed about 6(!) years ago, it would be great for StackOverflow to reconsider the request for 2FA.

Besides my remarks, I also have a question - how much 'interest' (or upvotes) should this post have in order to make it worthwile for StackOverflow to consider 2FA again?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The alternative to Martijn Pieters' answer [has just been mentioned on uber-meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256767/162730):

> So, over the last couple of weeks, I built a bare-bones two-factor authentication system for Stack Exchange OpenID.
>
> ...
>
> Before we ship this feature, we probably want to finish at least the site login/integration and SMS stuff. [...] Your input will help us determine whether to continue with the project or shelve it.

So if you want to use *Stack Exchange OpenID* and would like to have two-factor authentication for that, you should head over there and let folks know.

Comment: There wasn't enough interest in the project to continue with it, so it's been shelved. Sorry to everyone who was in support of it. :-(

Comment: I don't think 2FA is something you implement only if there is sufficient interest. You implement it if there there are significant security vulnerabilities to be addressed by implementing it. I believe there are, in this age of stolen identity databases and guessable passwords. It's the responsible thing to do, IME. And using a third party isn't sufficient on its own, since many folks don't like to tie accounts together on disparate services.

Comment: As of late May 2015, the linked page has been edited to add **We've decided that we won't be working on this project. Sorry to all the people who were in favour of it.** at the top.

Comment: I also agree that it's a matter of responsibility with one's users, not a matter of popularity. FIDO may never become popular as it requires buying a hardware device. Still, it's the current best solution for authentication. Using OpenID isn't an alternative, as one of FIDO's features is precisely privacy, so that our accounts on multiple services aren't tied together. IMHO one of the reasons OpenID is bad is because its base functionality relies on the main company knowing all the services and portals we're using it to login.

Answer (score -22):

Stack Exchange supports GitHub, Google and Facebook logins, all three of which support 2-factor authentication.

Just use one of those for your login and enable 2FA there.

The Stack Exchange 'native' login does not support 2FA at this time.

Comment: I'm downvoting this exactly for the reasons `theory` gave under the other answer: "And using a third party isn't sufficient on its own, since many folks don't like to tie accounts together on disparate services."

Comment: That’s good. I suppose it’s quite popular, although I don’t use it. I wish they’d add 2FA to “email logins”.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because I don't use Facebook or Google due to privacy concerns, and prefer keeping all logins isolated.

Comment: @BhaveshDiwan: that's fine, but for people that do want to use such accounts it provides a solution *now*, rather than having to wait for Stack Exchange to revert their decision (in May 2015) not to work on this feature.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that the recommendation is to delete the email login and require only Google or GitHub login? There are some challenges with logging in to add additional accounts this way, if you separate those accounts in different browser profiles. I personally think it's very odd that Stack Exchange "outsources" its login security to other platforms.

Comment: -1 because if you distrust both Google and Facebook you are left with inferior account security which is pretty embarrassing for a site network with this scope and focus.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold: sorry you feel that way, but those are the only options you can use *right now*. I note you do appear to trust GitHub, which is one of the supported options.