# Adding Security log option for seeing login activites

Tags: feature-request, login, security, logout, last-activity

Recently I was logged out of my SO account automatically. This happened 2 times in 2 days (like 1 today and 1 yesterday). Note also that this has happened in the past as well. Upon seeing this, I am thinking that maybe it is possible that someone has logged in with my username and password somewhere, and then logged out of there by clicking `log out of all devices`. Or maybe something else happened on the server side that resulted in me logging out of my account twice.

So I think that it would be good to have a Stack Overflow feature (like a separate menu item under the settings page) called `See login activity`, where **users would be able to see the information (IP addresses, locations etc.) of the devices that have recently been used to log in to this particular account.**

This way we can immediately change our passwords or take some other appropriate action if we see that someone has tried to log in to our account with our username. There is already a feature like this on *Github* under the `Security log` menu item. **Similarly, I want that whenever someone tries (either unsuccessfully or successfully) to log into the account, the event gets logged in our *security log* item.**

Comment: Can confirm several unintentional/random logouts in the last week.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [How can I see my stack exchange account login history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164632/how-can-i-see-my-stack-exchange-account-login-history)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I don't use StackID. Moreover, i am asking for a built in method/option to see login activity instead of using  other method/workaround like `StackID`. Ofcourse the suggested workaround is very useful.

Comment: Which login method do you use? At least for google and github, there should be a login protocol by the provider.

Comment: @BDL For github there is already an option called `Security Log` in their settings page where user can see the past logins' ip addresses and location. I want the same here(on SO etc). I mean here(on SO) also there should be a option called say, `Security log` under the settings page doing the same.

Comment: All your recent logins have happened from the same location; a certain large city in a very large country. Not sure if this helps you. If you believe that your account might be compromised, then you can ask mods to forcefully log you out, and then change your passwords. It's worth pointing out that a Stack Overflow account may have multiple account methods, so you should also look into cleaning this up.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for the reassurance. I was also looking into [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275333/why-doesnt-stack-exchange-support-2-factor-authentication-2fa) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230490/two-factor-authentication-for-stack-exchange).

Comment: I sometimes get logged out (even multiple times per day) but it's always on *.stackexchange.com and seems to happen when I'm rapidly visiting questions on sites I don't even have an account on.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Laurel. Maintaining my session on SO is easy, but my network session dies in hours. I suspect this is related to some deeper session bug rather than a security issue (though I don't disagree with needing a security log)

Comment: The last IP address used to visit is only a feature of [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=stats), shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQn7r.png

Comment: Yeah, [getting logged out from SO/SE automatically is a common issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=logged+out).

Comment: Are you using a Google account for auth? I have been logged out of various web sites (and all of my ChromeCasts!) multiple times this week.