# How to turn on two-step verification on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, security, privacy

I just joined Stack Overflow and I want to enable two-factor authentication, but I couldn't find it. Can you please tell me how to enable it?

I couldn't find the security tab in the settings; I looked at the bottom of the page but couldn't see it. Is there a page that I missed?

I am a first-day computer programming student on Stack Overflow. I looked in the settings for a few minutes but couldn't see it.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't Stack Exchange support 2-factor authentication (2FA)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275333)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow does not directly support 2FA (two-factor authentication) but it does support logging in with your google account which does support 2FA.

Go to your profile -> <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Your logins</kbd>. from there you can manage your access methods:

[image]